# Using SQL Server variables in clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Here is a simple example - why does this work:

```
DECLARE @v as varchar(75)
SET @v = 'xxx-xxxx'
SELECT * FROM tbl_skus WHERE SKU = @v
```

But this does not work:

```
DECLARE @v as varchar(75)
SET @v = 'xxx-xxxx,yyy-yyyy'
SELECT * FROM tbl_skus WHERE SKU IN ( @v )
```

Both SKUs 'xxx-xxxx' and 'yyy-yyyy'

are in the table. The first query pulls 1 result, and the second pulls 0 results; no errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot assign two values to a single variable. You will have to do something like this:

```
DECLARE @v as varchar(75) DECLARE @a as varchar(75)

SET @v = 'xxx-xxxx' SET @a = 'yyy-yyyy'

SELECT * FROM tbl_skus
WHERE SKU IN (@v, @a);
```

Answer (score 1):

The IN doesn't support passing in a list of values that way. Try it one of these two ways:

```
DECLARE @vList TABLE(v VARCHAR(75));

INSERT INTO @vList
VALUES('xxx-xxxx'),('yyy-yyyy');

SELECT * 
FROM tbl_skus 
WHERE SKU IN ( SELECT v FROM @vList)
```

Or you could:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl_skus
WHERE SKU IN ('xxx-xxxx','yyy-yyyy')
```

Answer (score 0):

First query eventually becomes `SELECT * FROM tbl_skus WHERE SKU ='xxx-xxxx'` , the second  - `SELECT * FROM tbl_skus WHERE SKU IN ('xxx-xxxx,yyy-yyyy')` (1 value passed to `IN` - it searches for SKU ='xxx-xxxx,yyy-yyyy'); to return 2 rows it must look `... IN ('xxx-xxxx','yyy-yyyy')`  (2 values passed).